# Array is not equal but it actually is?

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, xcode, swift4.2

This is so crazy. I'm comparing two Arrays of a custom type, but it says its not Equal but it actually is, because i printed all objects in it and checked them with `https://www.diffchecker.com` if they're different and they're not! Im using Swift 4.2

```
func deleteFavorite(_ favorite: Favorite) {
var oldFavorites = getFavoriteSurahs()

oldFavorites.forEach {
    $0.reciter.surahs.forEach {
        print($0.name)
        print($0.number)
    }
    print()

    favorite.reciter.surahs.forEach {
        print($0.name)
        print($0.number)
    }

    print(NSArray(array:
        $0.reciter.surahs).isEqual(favorite.reciter.surahs))
    // It prints false BUT IT SHOULD PRINT TRUE, BECAUSE THEY'RE ACTUALLY EQUAL
}
}
```

Thats my Surah class:

```
class Surah: NSObject, NSCoding {
private(set) public var name: String
private(set) public var number: Int

init(number: Int, name: String) {
    self.number = number
    self.name = name
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(self.number, forKey: "number")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    self.number = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "number")
}
}
```

And this is my `getFavoriteSurahs()` function:

```
func getFavoriteSurahs() -> [Favorite] {
    if let favoritesData = self.object(forKey: UD_FAVORITES) as? Data {
        do {
            let favorites = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(favoritesData) as! [Favorite]
            return favorites
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
            return [Favorite]()
        }
    } else {
        print("EMPTY Favorites")
        return [Favorite]()
    }
}
```

> > UPDATE
> >     This is so dump:

```
        print($0.surah.number == favorite.surah.number)
        print($0.surah.name == favorite.surah.name)
// Prints true

        print($0.surah == favorite.surah)
// Prints false
```

> > UPDATE 2

```
if $0.reciter.name == favorite.reciter.name && $0.reciter.image == favorite.reciter.image && $0.reciter.documentID == favorite.reciter.documentID &&
            $0.reciter.surahs.count == favorite.reciter.surahs.count &&

            $0.surah.number == favorite.surah.number &&
            $0.surah.name == favorite.surah.name {
            print("OMG FINALLY")
        } else {
            print("NOO NOO NOO")
        }
```

> > // Prints OMG FINALLY. After checking every single item. Is this normal??

Comment: Where is your equality defined? Why are you using NSArray in the first place?

Comment: Because i haven't found any other way to compare them. My initial thought was to check if an array contains an element of favorite but it always failed and printed false. Then i checked every step and only the surah thing wasn't equal

Comment: There was 2 right answers and you will not check them. -1 for you

Comment: I wasn't at the PC -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subclassing `NSObject` which implements the `Equatable` protocol, but by default only uses pointer equality. You need to override the `isEqual(_:)` method and `hash` property:

```swift
override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    guard let rhs = object as? Surah else { return false }
    return number == rhs.number && name == rhs.name
}

override var hash: Int {
    return number.hashValue ^ name.hashValue
}
```

```swift
let s1 = Surah(number: 1, name: "One")
let s2 = Surah(number: 1, name: "One")
s1 == s2       // => true
[s1] == [s2]   // => true
```

Comment: what means the "^"

Comment: and why i can't use the .contains() method

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **isEqual** of NSArray for custom objects (not from SDK), then you need to implement isEqual for that type of object. Something like that:

```
override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? MyClass {
       // check for every ivar that should be equal
            return foo == object.foo && bar == object.bar
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using the normal swift types. The NSArray this was just to showcase that these are "not equal". Look at the question again. I haven't found an elegant way

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` is a reference type, so you are checking if the two `NSArray` pointers are equal. You should be using the native Swift `Array` type, which does what you are looking for.

Comment: i haven't found any other way to compare them. My initial thought was to check if an array contains an element of favorite but it always failed and printed false. Then i checked every step and only the surah thing wasn't equal – SwiftNewling just now    Edit    Delete

Comment: Use swift arrays, and you will be able to compare them.

Comment: No, he is not checking whether array refernces are equal but he is using the NSObject.IsEqual to compare items for reference equality. Array equality in objc is based on comparing items too.

Comment: the arrays are normal swift types. I'm just using NSArray to get the function isEqual for printing

Comment: look the question again. Sorry